# Which of these two is correct?

Tags: grammar

I'm not sure if I need to add S to "elaborate" here.

"Each of the subsequent paragraphs elaborateS on these functionalities in order."

"Each of the subsequent paragraphs elaborate on these functionalities in order."

Why is your answer the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subject of the sentence is 'each of the subsequent paragraphs'. Since 'each' is singular you want the singular form of the verb i.e. 'elaborates'.